# how to only show int in a sorted list from csv file

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I have a huge CSV file where im supose to show only the colume "name" and "runtime"
My problem is that i have to sort the file and print the top 10 min and top 10 max from the 
row runtime and print them 
But the row 'runtime' contains text like this:

```
['http://dbpedia.org/ontology/runtime',
 'XMLSchema#double',
 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double',
'4140.0',
 '5040.0',
 '5700.0',
 '{5940.0|6600.0}',
 'NULL',
 '6480.0',....n]
```

how do i sort the list showing only numbers

my code so far:

```
import csv

run = []

fp = urllib.urlopen('Film.csv')

reader = csv.DictReader(fp,delimiter=',')

for line in reader:

    if line:
            run.append(line)

name = []

for row in run:

    name.append(row['name'])

    runtime = []

for row in run:

    runtime.append(row['runtime'])

runtime
```

expected output:

the csv file contaist null values and values looking like this {5940.0|6600.0}

expected output

```
 '4140.0',
 '5040.0',
 '5700.0',
 '6600.0',
 '6800.0',....n]
```

not containg the NULL values and only the higest values in the ones looking 
like this 
{5940.0|6600.0}

Comment: Please ident your code.

Comment: In other words you want to *filter* the data to only contain numbers? Please edit in the expected output of your program.

Comment: im new here sorry about the code!

Comment: but i want to filter it so it only contais numbers.

Comment: @msvalkon I think in summary, yes. [i for i in runtime if type(i) in (type(1),type(1.0)) should do? But that seems a little unpythonic.

Comment: I don't get it, where's the `name` coming from if the csv-file contains only NULL or numeric values?

Comment: Name is from another row in the csv file. But the file is so huge so if i print it it will crash

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it like this, but you should probably wait for better answers.

```
>>>l=[1,1.3,7,'text']
>>>[i for i in l if type(i) in (type(1),type(1.0))] #only ints and floats allowed
[1,1.3,7]
```

This should do though.

Answer (score 0):

My workflow probably would be: Use `str.isdigit()` as a filter, convert to a number with BIF `int()` or `float()` and then use `sort()` or `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* use one of the many answers that will show up here, I personally would exploit some domain knowledge of your csv file:

```
runtime = runtime[3:]
```

Based on your example value for the `runtime` row, the first three columns contain metadata. So you *know* more about the structure of your input file than just "it is a csv file".

Then, all you need to do is sort:

```
runtime = sorted(runtime)
max_10 = runtime[-10:]
min_10 = runtime[:10]
```

The syntax I'm using here is called "slice", which allows you to access a range of a sequence, by specifying the start index and the "up-to-but-not-including" index in the square brackets separated by a colon. Neat trick: Negative indexes wrap are seen as starting at the end of the sequence.